# Change branching point in git

Tags: git, github

We have two branches Branch1 and Branch2 which differs each other by 100 commits. I had created a new branch BranchA from Branch1. No commits have been made on BranchA.

Is there a way to change BranchA to appear it was branched from Branch2, so that I can make a commit and raise a pull request against Branch2 - but it won't carry any commits from Branch1?

Comment: Have you tried to delete `BranchA` and create it based on `Branch2`?

Comment: @zaratustra I can do that, just wanted to know if there is an option to update.

We have a tracker that shows branches created, and it will not update branch deletions - unfortunately. So it would be two branches for the same ticket, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no commits have been added to `BranchA` yet, you can simply reset it to `Branch2`:

```
git checkout BranchA
git reset --hard Branch2
```

---

Had there been any commits on `BranchA` that you needed to keep, you could have opted for a rebase:

```
git checkout BranchA
git rebase Branch2
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.